# Test Get action in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have created a Web API project and created one SampleController in the controller folder. By default there are certain methods in SampleController.

```
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

I have create another method

```
public byte[] Get(string toByte)
{
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(toByte);
}
```

Now how can I check whether it is returning byte array or not?

Comment: I recommend you write some unit tests for your binary serializing method if you want to check what it is doing.

Comment: which binary serializing method?

Comment: Your method that takes a string and turns it into an array of bytes.

Comment: Not mine ;) I don't think the OP wants to test the encoding (not serialization) but that the method is invoked correctly, and returns soemthing. In any case, if he wanted to test taht funcionality he'd rather move it to another class and test that class. Testing the Web API is much more complex than a simple unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you have the default route registered, type the controllers route URL in your browser:

http://myserver/api/controllername/

and you'll get the first action invoked.

Type the controllers route in the URL, but including a toByte parameter in the query string, like this:

http://myserver/api/controllername?toByte=xyz

and you'll invoke the second action.

Or you can use the excellent Postman complement for chrome to be able to test any kind of method, add headers to your request, etc. With the "simple method of typing the URL" explained above, you can only test GET actions. With Postman you can try other methods like POST, PUT, DELETE...

*NOTE: as you don't specify an accept header (because you cannot do that directly in the browser) you'll receive an XML response. With Postman you can include the header to get JSON*

Comment: when I enter the way you have said, this is the message that is showing in the browser " This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below. " and followed by a code i.e: 

<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<string>value1</string>
<string>value2</string>
</ArrayOfstring>

Comment: when I pass through query string (http://localhost:59313/api/SampleAPI?toByte=%22Test%22) this is displaying in the browser " This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below. " & " <base64Binary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">IgAAAFQAAABlAAAAcwAAAHQAAAAiAAAA</base64Binary> "

Comment: That's exactly how an Array looks like in XML. That's not an error, it's your browser telling you that it doesn't knows how to show it in a "beautiful way" (i.e. using an XML style sheet to pretty print it). So, you're getting an array with two strings within: the test was succesful. But you must be invling another controller, because your controller doesn't return an array of strings with "value1" and "value2" inside. Please, check the controller's name in your URL.

Comment: If you want to see it in a more readable way, install Postman and inclue the header "accept: application/json". This tells the server tro return the result in the JSON format which is much more readable.